# Set values of all rows with the value of selected row

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I have table like this:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | test1 | ... |
| 2  | test2 | ... |
| 3  | test3 | ... |
| 4  | test4 | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
```

What I want is that all of them will have same `name`, for example `test2`, it depends on the `id`. **I don't want solution, where I manually write that value.** So when I entered number `2`, it will change all row's name to the `test2`, because `id = 2 is test2`.

I tried this command:

```
UPDATE table SET name = t.name SELECT t.* FROM table AS t WHERE id = 2;
```

My expecting solution would be:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | test2 | ... |
| 2  | test2 | ... |
| 3  | test2 | ... |
| 4  | test2 | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
```

PS: my table haven't got that name, also structure is completely different, but I have used this jsut for the example.

Comment: provide us with an sql fiddle, this way it's much easier for people to test their possible solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update table SET name =
   (Select name 
    from table 
    where id = 2)
```

if this does not work in MySQL, then try this

```
Update t SET name =
   (Select name 
    from table 
    where id = 2)
From table t
```

Correct syntax for MariaDB as discovered by OP:

```
UPDATE table as t, 
     (SELECT name FROM table 
      WHERE id = 2) as temp
  SET t.name = temp.name
```

Comment: #1093 - Table 'table' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Yes..  --------------   So?  This is perfectly fine. Does it not work in MySQL ?

Comment: Ooh, sorry, I made a mistake :) I don't have MySQL, but MariaDB. I have MySQL on the another computer. It seems like that ALIAS is not working in the MariaDB. But it works in the SELECT.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with MariaDB, can't help you with syntax for that product, especially if its not standard SQL.

Comment: Well, I have found a solution :) So the command for the MariaDB would be like this (also you can enter it into your answer, so it will be more visible):

`UPDATE table as t, (SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = 2) as temp SET t.name = temp.name`

Answer (score 1):

No better, but perhaps less cryptic:

```
SELECT @thename := name  FROM table  WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE table  SET name = @thename;
```